# Invalid object name 'dbo.Customers'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2014

I am using Entity Framework with a code-first approach for ASP.NET MVC 5 with a SQL Server 2014 database. The application is already available in a production environment. Now I am looking to add a new table to the existing database.

Here are the steps that I have followed :

1. Added the Model class `Customer.cs` within the `Models` folder in the `Data` project
2. Updated the context class `SampleDBContext` class with the new model

   ```
   public class SampleDBContext : DbContext
   {
       public IDbSet<Customer> Customers{ get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Created a SQL script corresponding to the above model class and executed it against the database
4. Now on running the application, I get an error which says

   > Invalid object name 'dbo.Customers'

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue?

Comment: That error is coming from SQL Server, and means exactly what it says.  Use SSMS to check the table in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an SQL error. The database being accessed does not have an SQL object (such as a table, in this case).

You need to create a `[dbo].[Customers]` table. For some reason, your 3rd step did not properly create a `[dbo].[Customers]` table on the database you are accessing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution fixed the issue now :)

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro Glad to hear it's working. Cheers.